# Copy Folder command in VBScript issues

Tags: vbscript

I have a hierarchy of folders like 1st -2nd-Files that I am trying to copy using this command  `FSO.CopyFolder strInputPath, strOutPutPath, true`

It copies everything correctly but when I run this command again it does not copy the new files that I place in the 2nd folder..I was thinking putting `true` in the `CopyFolder` command overwrites everything inside..

Comment: According to this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbfwysex(v=vs.84).aspx), you can use wildcard in the source path `strInputPath`. You can do recursive folder and file copy. But easiest solution will be use `robocopy` command with mirror `/MIR` option.

Comment: What do you mean by 2nd folder? What exactly are you doing when you run the command again? Are you trying to overwrite what you copied in the first place? 

You are correct that the 'true' parameter should overwrite everything. Note that CopyFolder will stop if it encounters an error, perhaps the file permissions do not allow you to overwrite the files?